# How Do I Properly Submit Two Forms Within One HTML Structure?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to submit a create view with two forms.  The code below works fine if everything is filled out and the form submitted.  However if fields are omitted in form2...the form submission fails and the field that was filled out for "form"..."name"....gets reset.  I've read you can do multiple forms and I've largely got this working...I just need to figure out how to incorporate form2 into the if_valid()....  Here's my view...

```
def tasklist_detail_view(request, id):
    context = {}
    context["tasklist"] = TaskList.objects.get(id=id)
    context["tasks"] = Task.objects.filter(task_list=id).all()

    obj = get_object_or_404(TaskList, id=id)
    form = UpdateTaskListForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    form2 = TaskForm(request.POST or None)
    context["task_list_id"] = id

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("MyTaskLists:my_task_list_main_menu"))

    context["form"] = form
    context["form2"] = form2

    return render(request, "my_task_list_tasklist_detail.html", context)
```

My HTML...

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="forms">
 {% csrf_token %}
 
   {{ form.name }}
       
   {% include "my_task_list_task_create_form1.html" with tasklist=tasklist %}
  
   <button type="submit" class="button66" name="status" value="Submitted">Submit</button>
    
 </form>
```

And then in my include HTML...

```
<div id="task-list-form" hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">    
        
<button class="button35" hx-post="{% url 'MyTaskLists:task-create' id=task_list_id %}">Save</button>
               
    {{ form2 }}
```

I did try to do something like....

```
if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("MyTaskLists:my_task_list_main_menu"))
```

But then nothing happens...the forms are not accepted at all even if the fields are filled out properly....From what I've read I understand the POST is being applied to both forms....if one is not filled out properly that is why the other errors out?  I just can't quite figure out how to process them both properly.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two forms to behave like one form, and save two objects only if both forms are valid, then the logic is

```
if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
    form.save()
    form2.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("MyTaskLists:my_task_list_main_menu"))

context["form"] = form
context["form2"] = form2
return render(request, "my_task_list_tasklist_detail.html", context)
```

If there is any field with the same name in `form` and `form2` you need to use a prefix to remove the ambiguity.

```
form = UpdateTaskListForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj, prefix='form1')
form2 = TaskForm(request.POST or None, prefix='form2')
```